# JQuery Overlay - Change OnClick to OnMouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery overlay, like this one:

```
$("a[rel]").overlay({
    mask: '#EFEFEF',
    close: "a.closeOverlayBtn",
    closeOnClick: false
});
```

This works by clicking a link, like this one:

```
<a href="foo" class="bar" rel="#overlay1">baz</a>
```

How can I modify this to work by `onmouseover` instead of `onclick`?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the plugin you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could trigger the click event onmouseover.

```
$('a[rel]').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).trigger('click');
});
```